# Injecting JS to script tag inside HTML

Tags: javascript, code-injection

[text](https://alxtpl.github.io/Balls/)

Hello everybody trying to inject js to script tag
Iam trying to make big amount boucing balls with color, border, size change
I have luck with one. I made decision to inject js to script tag from while loop.
And now i have issue that only first div get colorized. If somebody can help please do it.

[Changing color only in first div why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOpmR.png)
[github](https://alxtpl.github.io/Balls/)

```
var positionX = 0;
var positionY = 0;
var velocityY = 50;
var velocityX = 50;
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
var reverseX = false;
var reverseY = false;
var Xmin = 0;
var Ymin = 0;
var Xmax = 800;
var Ymax = 300;
var BallsCount = 5;

var newElement = document.createElement("script");
var scriptTag = document.body.appendChild(newElement);

var newElement2 = document.createElement("style");
var styleTag = document.body.appendChild(newElement2);

scriptTag.id = "scr";
styleTag.id = "stl";

var t = document.getElementById("scr");
var s = document.getElementById("stl");
var d = document.getElementById("div1");

var count = 0;
do {
  // console.log(count);
  var newElement3 = document.createElement("div");
  var divTag = document.body.appendChild(newElement3);
  divTag.id = "div" + count;

  s.innerHTML +=
    "#div" +
    count +
    " {z-index: " +
    count +
    "; position: absolute; left: 0px; left: 0px; top: 200px; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%; background:black;}\
    ";
  ////////////

  t.textContent +=
    "\
    function randomNumber" +
    count +
    "(min, max) {\
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;\
    }\
    function chcolor" +
    count +
    "() {\
      var r = randomNumber" +
    count +
    "(0, 255);\
      var g = randomNumber" +
    count +
    "(0, 255);\
      var b = randomNumber" +
    count +
    "(0, 255);\
        div" +
    count +
    ".style.background = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';\
      }\
      setInterval(chcolor" +
    count +
    ", 900);\
    \
    ";

  count++;
} while (BallsCount >= count);

/////////

function chsize() {
  var blsz = randomNumber(30, 700);
  ball.style.width = blsz + "px";
  ball.style.height = blsz + "px";
}

function chborder() {
  ball.style.borderRadius = randomNumber(30, 50) + "%";
}

function moveBall() {
  if (reverseX === false) {
    positionX = positionX + velocityX;
    ball.style.left = positionX + "px";
  } else {
    positionX = positionX - velocityX;
    ball.style.left = positionX + "px";
  }

  if (reverseY === false) {
    positionY = positionY + velocityY;
    ball.style.top = positionY + "px";
  } else {
    positionY = positionY - velocityY;
    ball.style.top = positionY + "px";
  }

  if (positionY > Ymax || positionY === Ymin) {
    reverseY = !reverseY;
  }

  if (positionX > Xmax || positionX === Xmin) {
    reverseX = !reverseX;
  }
}

// setInterval(moveBall, 100);
// setInterval(chborder, 900);
// setInterval(chsize, 1000);
```

Comment: You are trying to change the color of each dynamically created div using the chcolor functions, but the functions are defined in the global scope and refer to the div with the id div+count, which is not directly accessible in the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the color of each dynamically created div using the chcolor functions, but the functions are defined in the global scope and refer to the div with the id div+count, which is not directly accessible in the function.

```js
    var positionX = 0;
    var positionY = 0;
    var velocityY = 50;
    var velocityX = 50;
    var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
    var reverseX = false;
    var reverseY = false;
    var Xmin = 0;
    var Ymin = 0;
    var Xmax = 800;
    var Ymax = 300;
    var BallsCount = 5;
    
    var newElement = document.createElement("script");
    var scriptTag = document.body.appendChild(newElement);
    
    var newElement2 = document.createElement("style");
    var styleTag = document.body.appendChild(newElement2);
    
    scriptTag.id = "scr";
    styleTag.id = "stl";
    
    var t = document.getElementById("scr");
    var s = document.getElementById("stl");
    
    var count = 0;
    do {
      var newElement3 = document.createElement("div");
      var divTag = document.body.appendChild(newElement3);
      divTag.id = "div" + count;
    
      s.innerHTML +=
        "#div" +
        count +
        " {z-index: " +
        count +
        "; position: absolute; left: 0px; left: 0px; top: 200px; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%; background:black;}\
        ";
    
      t.textContent +=
        "\
        function randomNumber" +
        count +
        "(min, max) {\
          return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;\
        }\
        function chcolor" +
        count +
        "(div) {\
          var r = randomNumber" +
        count +
        "(0, 255);\
          var g = randomNumber" +
        count +
        "(0, 255);\
          var b = randomNumber" +
        count +
        "(0, 255);\
          div.style.background = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';\
        }\
        setInterval(function() { chcolor" + count + "(document.getElementById('div" + count + "')); }, 900);\
        ";
      
      count++;
    } while (BallsCount >= count);

    function chsize() {
      var blsz = randomNumber(30, 700);
      ball.style.width = blsz + "px";
      ball.style.height = blsz + "px";
    }
    
    function chborder() {
      ball.style.borderRadius = randomNumber(30, 50) + "%";
    }
    
    function moveBall() {
      if (reverseX === false) {
        positionX = positionX + velocityX;
        ball.style.left = positionX + "px";
      } else {
        positionX = positionX - velocityX;
        ball.style.left = positionX + "px";
      }
    
      if (reverseY === false) {
        positionY = positionY + velocityY;
        ball.style.top = positionY + "px";
      } else {
        positionY = positionY - velocityY;
        ball.style.top = positionY + "px";
      }
    
      if (positionY > Ymax || positionY === Ymin) {
        reverseY = !reverseY;
      }
    
      if (positionX > Xmax || positionX === Xmin) {
        reverseX = !reverseX;
      }
    }
    
    // setInterval(moveBall, 100);
    // setInterval(chborder, 900);
    // setInterval(chsize, 1000);
```

Comment: Please remove your redundant comment.